# Using loggable from knplabs doctrine behaviors with log table

Tags: symfony

I've setuped KnpLabs Doctrine Behaviors on a new symphony2 project, and I need to implement the [loggable](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#loggable) behavior to log entities' changes on my database.

Based on this example : https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors/issues/96, here is what I've done :

## /acme/MyBundle/Ressources/config/services.yml:

`services:
    knp.doctrine_behaviors.loggable_subscriber.logger_callable:
        class: acme\MyBundle\DatabaseLogger\DatabaseLogger
        arguments: ['@doctrine.entity_manager']`

## /acme/MyBundle/DatabaseLogger\DatabaseLogger.php:

`namespace acme\MyBundle\DatabaseLogger;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\LoggerInterface;
    use acme\MyBundle\Entity\Log;
    class DatabaseLogger
    {
        private $em;
        public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
        {
             $this->em = $em;
        }
        public function __invoke($message)
        {
             $this->em->persist(new Log($message));
             $this->em->flush();
        }
}`

Do you have any idea why it isn't working ?

Comment: Please elaborate on how "it isn't working". Post error messages or informations on discrepancies between the expected and the actual behaviour.

Comment: In fact, nothing happens :-( It seems that my service definition is not overriding default one, as I can see this into Symphony Profiler : DEBUG - acme\MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity #3 : property "name" changed from "test" to "test2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, my problem was a little different, I've forgotten to import my bundle's services.yml into my /app/config/config.yml file :-S :

`imports:
    - { resource: @acmeMyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml }`

From this point, my DatabaseLogger is called instead of the standard LoggerCallable