# Loggable capability for entity with trace of persistance place (location) - doctrine

Tags: symfony, logging, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Hi I am using `Doctrine` with [DoctrineBehaviors](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors) bundle in order to log history of changes for entities. Everything is working fine except one thing. I will need information where is the location of change that is going to be saved. For example if that change happened in cron command or in front end controller by some user etc.

Logging class is looking like this ([similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671790/using-loggable-from-knplabs-doctrine-behaviors-with-log-table)) :

```
/** service: "entity_logger" **/
class EntityLogger
{
   /**
    * @var EntityManager
    */
   protected $em;

   public function __construct(EntityManager $em = null)
   {
       $this->em = $em;
   }
   function __invoke($message)
   {
       $this->em->persist(new LogMessage($message));
       $this->em->flush();
   }
}
```

and it's set as service. So my question is how to manage information of location of change? I will need somehow to send beside entity that is going to be persist one more thing: location of that change. As I see it there are at least two options :

**A)** store value of location to that service "entity_logger" before persist/flush happens. Have property "location" inside service and put it into LogMessage obj. Something like:

```
$this->get('entity_logger')->setCurrentLocation("Cron for sync");
$this->em->persist($entityOne);
$this->em->flush();
```

**B)** get stack trace and see what class has call persist/flush and then see how to handle that information

First option requires editing of all current locations of persist and second one don't have that overhead but what is the better approach?

Is there even better way of doing that?

Thanks